# Upload images to server from Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, image-uploading

I've uploaded some images on a java server where I save their path in my database and the actual images in the path "/src/main/resources/static/image-uploads/*.img".

When I'm trying to load at the same time the images they seem to appear as broken (that tiny image).
However if I restart my server they seem to be able to load.

When I inspect element I can see the correct path in the src tag of html (I even copied it by adding the C:/users/.../ prefix and I can see the image).

I've read some possible solutions like opening Google Chrome with disable extensions flag but none of them worked. I've also tried to change the path to an absolute path but the problem still persists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Isn't HTML and Java server for back end primary tools for programming?

Comment: Your question appears to be off topic about browsers. It's not but it's still "off topic" cause you give us nothing to work with to help you. No code. No config information, etc.

Comment: You're right, let me edit my question